# Weird behavior with Text and View

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I have a MapView, with a text above it:

```
<View style={{ height: 310, alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: 10 }}>
    <MapView style={ { height: 300, width: 350, } } initialRegion= .. >

    <View style={{ height: 60, backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)' , flexDirection: 'column'}}>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}} >
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, color: 'black' }}>  {this.state.title} </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <Text style={{ marginTop: 5, fontSize: 15, color: 'black', marginRight: 13}}>  {this.state.startLoc.name} </Text>
            <Text style={{ marginTop: 5, fontSize: 15, backgroundColor: 'transparent', color: 'black' }}>  {buildTimeString(new Date(this.state.startDate))} </Text>
            <Text style={{ marginTop: 5, fontSize: 15, backgroundColor: 'transparent', color: 'black' }}>  {getDistanceOneToOne(this.state.startLoc, this.state.destinationLoc).distance} </Text>
        </View>
    </View> 
..
</View>
```

Sometimes it displays the two texts (lines) right, but most of the times it displays them wrong (bot above each other):

[image]

What could be the issue?

Comment: i think you forgot to close `MapView` : `<MapView style={ { height: 300, width: 350, } } initialRegion= .. />`

Comment: Hey @Ali no I did not and sorry for the mirepresentation. Sometime the flex fails but not always, it is wierd.

Comment: When they do overlap, right click and choose _Inspect_, and you will be able to see their actual CSS styles. With that you most likely will be able to debug your issue.